# Change the formatting when creating a new class in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, formatting, flash-cs5

I think I'm having difficulties thinking of the right way to word this question in the search box:

I'm looking for a way to change the way a new class is formatted when I create a new class in Flash CS5. I'm very particular with my formatting, especially the placement of curly braces, and I hate the default way AS3 classes are formatted.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can't find any setting in Flash Pro, you can look into Flash Builder or Flash Develop as they might have some more advanced options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- Create your own new class template that you copy & paste.
- Look at a new IDE for your code - I strongly suggest this if you're serious about doing some heavy ActionScript anyway - [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is amazing.
- Use the below dialogue to make adjustments to how the auto-format button will affect your code and then use the auto-format feature when you create a new class:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks -- FlashDevelop actually looks nice. I'll toy with it.